# Host Key verification failed when ssh from windows command prompt?

Tags: linux, ssh

When I tried to ssh my account on FreeBSD. It showed that host key verification failed. Some people say that I need to remove the old key. But I don't know what exactly is causing the problem. The picture on the top is the situation I saw and the picture at the bottom is the content of the known_hosts file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have been told is correct, the problem is here that the destination machine's host key pair has changed and your machine is still referring to the old key.

The solution is actually there in the error you are getting, just remove the key from the known_hosts and then ssh again and it will ask you to add the new key to known_host file which will fix your problem.

One thing I noticed is that you are doing ssh to `localhost` and that too on a custom port 3022. Since you are windows and it does not comes with ssh server by default, have you enabled the `ssh` server on windows and if yes have you configured it to use port 3022 instead of 22 which is default ?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled the ssh server on windows and I have configured it to use port 3022 for a school assignment.

Comment: Wait what is the old key here? There is nothing in the known_hosts file that matches the content of the error except for the number 256.

Comment: I hope you referring to the known_hosts file at the same location that is being shown in the error, if yes then just take a backup of your known_hosts file and remove it and then ssh again.

Comment: I did not downvote anything, it was somebody else, but I can try upvote it.

Comment: Sure please do, and accept the answer if it is helpful and solves your issue.

Comment: Can I ask one more thing, after I removed the file, and tried ssh, but the same error still showed up.

Comment: can you please check if the file exists at this location `C:\\Users\Thomas/.ssh/` ? If yes can you please remove and if you ssh again it will ask you add the new key to `known_hosts` file